# How to change this java code to clojure with same function?

Tags: java, clojure

How to change this java code to clojure?Let clojure code do the same thing?

B.java:

```
package b;

public class B {
 int c;
}
```

A.java:

```
package b;

import java.util.*;

public class A {

 public static void findElement(List<B> a)
 {
    a.forEach((z) -> {
        if (z.c == 1) {
            System.out.println(z.c);
        }
    });
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    B x = new B();
    x.c = 1;
    B y = new B();
    y.c = 2;
    List<B> d = new ArrayList<B>();
    d.add(x);
    d.add(y);
    findElement(d);
 }
}
```

I have tried to use defrecord and defprotocol times,but failed

Thanks!

Comment: Please also add what you have tried - it will give more insight on what you are really after and it might help to write a better answer (if only for copy-and-pasting some code).  Also what is the goal here? The code in classes looks quite random and are things that are basically one-liners in clojure.  Are you after `:gen-class` related things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using lots of mutations in your example. Clojure is a language that highly encourages immutability.

Here is a short snippet:

```
(defrecord B [c])

(defn find-element [bs]
  (filter #(= (:c %) 1) bs))

(let [x (->B 1)
      y (->B 2)
      d [x y]
      r (find-element d)]
  (doseq [i r]
    (println (:c i))))
```

However, instead of printing the elements inside `find-element`, we return the found results and store them in `r`. Later we use `doseq` to go over every item to print it.

This is not a very idiomatic way to think in Clojure, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this is a little bloated and OO-full.

I'd recommend going over [clojure basics](https://www.braveclojure.com/) and maybe practicing on [4clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) to internalize the different approach of Clojure.